# How to change MVC3+ Views after application has been deployed (without redeploying)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

As I understand one of the benefits of the MVC pattern is being able to substitute other Views without having to change the Model or Controller.

Since the Razor view engine compiles the views, how can I change or tweak the views after they have been deployed without having to re-deploy the application?

Comment: How are you deploying? You should just be able to copy over the `.cshtml` file - the view is compiled when requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor views are compiled dynamically at runtime when they are requested by the ASP.NET runtime. You could replace your `.cshtml/.vbhtml` files directly on your webserver and the changes will be automatically picked up.

Comment: This stands true for Pre Compiled Razor Views also?

Comment: But if you precompile your Razor views you no longer need to be deploying any `.cshtml` files to your webserver. So what exactly is your question? I though you were asking how to replace only `.cshtml` files on your webserver and changes would take effect immediately, but if you precompile there are no longer any `.cshtml` files. Sorry, I am confused.

Comment: Do I lose the ability to change the views if the application is deployed with pre-compiled views?

Comment: But what views are you talking about? If you precompile your Razor views there are no longer .cshtml files on your web server. So to answer your question, yes, you lose that ability.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answers. This is precisely what I wanted to know.